# Code reaches solution 'faster', how does that impact big O runtime?

Tags: python

I am working through a problem involving a 2D Matrix: https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix-ii/.

Here is my solution

```
class Solution:
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: bool
        """

        if len(matrix) == 0 or len(matrix[0]) == 0:
            return False

        height = len(matrix)
        width = len(matrix[0])

        row = height - 1 
        col = 0

        while col < width and row >= 0:
            if matrix[row][col] > target:
                row -= 1
            elif matrix[row][col] < target:
                col += 1
            else:
                return True

        return False
```

Runtime is O(n + m), where n and m are the lengths of an individual column and row, respectively.

So in my solution I start from the bottom left corner. You can also start from the top right corner with my approach. I am wondering, what if I implement my code so I search starting from both the bottom left and top right corner. One would expect I get to the target "faster", however, what would my runtime be in this case?

Comment: Why might we expect it to be faster to do two searches instead of one?

Comment: Let's say target is 1 move from top right and 8 from bottom left. If you just did one search (say bottom left), you would still reach the target. But if you do both searches simultaneously, you will reach the target 'faster', aka it will only take 1 move instead of 8.

Comment: Not sure how this affects overall Big O runtime though.

Comment: Do you mean using multi-threading? Anyway, the answer is that it doesn't change the asymptotic complexity because each of those searches still takes O(m + n) time.

Comment: OK. Asymptotically is it like O(m + n) + O(m + n) = O(2m + 2n) aka just O(m + n)? And then the average time is halved? Are you sure it's halved and not like logged?

Comment: Unless you're somehow doing both searches simultaneously, you still end up searching over the same area in the same time.

Comment: If they're simultaneous then it's like min( O(m + n), O(m + n) ) = O(m + n), but yes.